# Function without return doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that calls a function:

```
Function escreve_mapa(Row As Integer, LastColumn As Integer, equipamentos As interger, Abrangencia As String, medias)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim colunas As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Sheets("Mapa de sinais (tabela)").Select
    Cells(Row, "A").Value = Abrangencia
    Cells(Row, "B").Value = equipamentos
    Set cell = Range("C" & Row)
    Set colunas = Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, LastColumn - 3))
    i = 0
    For Each cell In colunas
        If medias(i, 1) > 0 Then
            cell.Value = Round(medias(i, 0) / medias(i, 1), 2)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
End Function
```

But when it gets to this function it returns the error User-defined type not defined

Any idea why?

Comment: would be easier for you and us if you tell the line where the error happens

Comment: The error happens here:                                                Function escreve_mapa(Row As Integer, LastColumn As Integer, equipamentos As interger, Abrangencia As String, medias)

Comment: SO that seems to be a compile error, not a runtime error ? 
Do your calling arguments match the types required by your function ?

Comment: i think so, but now that you ask, i have a doubt about medias, on the macro that calls this function it is Dim mediasPD(35, 1), do you think that's the problem?

Comment: `equipamentos As interger` interger <> integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a typo in your functions (although as it doesn't return anything it could be a sub) arguments.

`equipamentos As interger` should be `equipamentos As Integer`

Comment: correcting the typo and changing it into a sub solved my problem, Thanks for the help :)